# StreamGobbler short output or very quick process

Tags: java, io

I use StreamGobbler to read output from external program. Before I used to read and parse big(20-40 strings) output from stderr of ffmpeg. Now I want to read and parse only one string from stdout(one string is all output of program and this program ends very quickly) of identify(ImageMagick). And sometimes it works, but sometimes I have error "Stream closed". I think that StreamGobbler has no time to work with stream(process ends before streamGobler do some work).

Below you can see class ExecThread and example of it's usage.

Sorry for my English...

```
    String command =  ffmpegExe.getAbsolutePath()+ " -i \""+ fileName +"\"";
    ExecThread thread = new ExecThread(command);
    thread.setPriority(ExecThread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    thread.start();
    thread.waitFor(DEFAULT_WAIT);

    //reading ffmpeg stderr
    BufferedReader ffmpegErr = thread.getErrBufferedReader();
    String line;

    try
    {
        while((line = ffmpegErr.readLine()) !=null)
//some code



private static class ExecThread extends  Thread
{
    public ExecThread(String command)
    {
        this.command = command;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        try
        {
            ExecCommand(command);
            exitVal = process.waitFor();
        }
        catch (Exception e )
        {
            logger.error("Error while executing command: " + command + e.getMessage(),e);
            System.err.println("Error");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    public void waitFor(long millis)
    {
        try
        {
            this.join(millis);
            process.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Error while interupting command: " + command + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }


    private  void ExecCommand(String command) throws IOException
    {
        //run command
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        process = rt.exec(new String[]{shellName,shellOption, command}, null, null);

        //get stderr buffered reader
        StreamGobbler errGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream());
        StreamGobbler outGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream());

        ErrBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errGobbler));
        OutBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outGobbler));

    }
    private BufferedReader ErrBufferedReader;

    public BufferedReader getOutBufferedReader()
    {
        return OutBufferedReader;
    }

    private BufferedReader OutBufferedReader;
    private Process process;
    private String command;
    private int exitVal=-1;

    public BufferedReader getErrBufferedReader()
    {
        return ErrBufferedReader;
    }

    public Process getProcess()
    {
        return process;
    }

    public String getCommand()
    {
        return command;
    }

    public int getExitVal()
    {
        return exitVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend two changes:

1. Use the [Java Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html) instead of writing a Thread.
2. Close your input, output, and error streams and destroy the Process.  You'll have file handle leaks if you don't.

Comment: I use Process, but it runs in other(not in main) Thread. And I destroy it in function waitFor

Comment: You don't close your streams.  Grief will ensure unless you're sure that destroy takes care of it for you.

Comment: Thanks! I added closing of StreamGobblers and BufferedReaders. But without sleep(see my answer for question) it not solve problem..

Comment: You shouldn't need the sleep.

Comment: I know that using sleep is not good, but without sleep it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

This is not good decision but it works. Before it was `String command =   identifyExe.getAbsolutePath() + " \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";`
now it `String command =  "sleep 1 ; " + identifyExe.getAbsolutePath() + " \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";`

Sleep is very usefull function :-)

But, if you know better decision please tell...

Comment: One bit of advice: You can answer your own question under certain circumstances, but you're not supposed to simulate a conversation.  I would not write it the way you're doing it.